# Change in MongoDB 2.6 with Positional Operator

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a (Morphia) entity, which embeds another entity:

```
@Entity(value = "connection", noClassnameStored = false)
public class ConnectorEntity {
    @Embedded
    private List<UnavailabilityEntity> unavailabilities = new ArrayList<>();
```

And the embedded entity:

```
@Embedded
public class UnavailabilityEntity implements Serializable {
    private Date start = new Date();
    // Do not use a null value as Morphia (as of 0.99.1) cannot handle this on embedded lists
    private Date end = new Date(0);
```

Adding an unavailability works fine. So there's a list of unavailable entities and if something is currently unavailable, one of them has `end = new Date(0)`.

Once the connector is available again, I want to "close" the unavailability by setting `end = new Date()`.

The following query is working fine in MongoDB 2.4, but isn't working in 2.6, if I want to add a second unavailability (adding and closing one is working fine):

```
@Override
public void addAvailability(final String connectionUuid) {
    Query<ConnectorEntity> query = mongoDataStore.find(ConnectorEntity.class)
        .field("uuid").equal(connectionUuid)
        .field("unavailabilities.start").exists()
        .field("unavailabilities.end").hasThisOne(new Date(0));

    // If there is an open unavailability - close it
    if (query.get() != null) {
        UpdateOperations<ConnectorEntity> update = mongoDataStore
            .createUpdateOperations(ConnectorEntity.class).disableValidation()
            .set("unavailabilities.$.end", new Date());
        mongoDataStore.update(query, update);
    }
}
```

So I assume the positional operator `$` isn't applied to the right unavailability. Did something in MongoDB change that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Perhaps you could enable [query logging](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/) on `mongod` `2.4` and `2.6` and compare the generated queries?

Comment: Did you work out your query issue? If the *only* thing that has changed is your MongoDB server version then it seems possible the query might be handled differently in MongoDB 2.6 vs 2.4, and it would be worth profiling/explaining the specific query that is being generated. If you've changed anything else (for example, are querying against a different data set or using different Morphia versions) that makes it harder to isolate the problem.

Comment: I have only changed the MongoDB version, nothing else. I'll give it another try in a few weeks, but the upgrade is not urgent for us at the moment, so it will take some time